# Convert nested JSON convert to CSV with DataWeave in Mule 4

Tags: csv, mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have this transform message:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "one": [
    "two": payload.one.two,
    "three": payload.one.three,
    "four": {
    "five": payload.one.four.five map (item, index) -> {
    five : item
     as DateTime 
     {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx"}
      as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"} 
},
    "six":{
        "seven": payload.one.four.six.seven,
        "eight": payload.one.four.six.eight
    },
        "nine": {
            "name": payload.one.four.nine.name
            
        },
    "tenCreated":payload.one.four.tenCreated map (item, index) -> {
    tenCreated : item
     as DateTime 
     {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx"}
      as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"},
      
      },
    "elevenUpdated": payload.one.four.elevenUpdated map (item, index) -> {
    elevenUpdated : item
     as DateTime 
     {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx"}
      as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
      
     },
    "twelve": {
        "thirteen": payload.one.four.twelve.thirteen
    },
    "fifteen": {
        "name": payload.one.four.fifteen.name
    },
    "sixteen":{
        "sixteenCreator": payload.one.four.sixteen.sixteenCreator,
        "seventeen": payload.four.one.sixteen.seventeen
    },
    "eieighteen": payload.one.four.eieighteen,
    "ninteen: {
        "ninteeneReporter": payload.one.four.ninteen.ninteeneReporter,
        "twentyEmail": payload.one.four.ninteen.twentyEmail
    },
    "twentyOne":{
        "TwentyTwo": payload.one.four.twentyOne.TwentyTwo,
        "TwnetyThree": payload.one.four.twentyOne.TwnetyThree
    },
    "TwentyFour": {
        "TwentyFive": payload.one.four.TwentyFour.TwentyFive,
        "TwentySix":{
            "TwentySeven": payload.one.four.TwentyFour.TwentySix.TwentySeven,
            "TwentyEight": payload.one.four.TwentyFour.TwentySix.TwentyEight.name,
            "Thiry": payload.one.four.TwentyFour.TwentySix.Thiry.name,
            "ThirtyOne": payload.isuues.four.TwentyFour.TwentySix.ThirtyOne.name
        }   
    }
    }
    
    ] reduce (element,acc={}) -> acc ++ element
}
```

This transform message as output looks like this:

```
{
    "one": {
        "two": [
             "199052",
            "109926"
        
         
        ],
        "three": [
            "191",
            "190",
            "189",
            "188",
            "187"
       
        ],
        "four": {
            "five": [
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-18"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-18"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-18"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-14"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-14"
                },
            
            ],
            "six": {
                "seven": [
                   "Test1",
                    "Test2",
                     "Test1",
                    "Test2"
       
                ],
                "eight": [
                   "first description.",
                    "second description",
                     "first description.",
                    "second description"
                  
                ]
            },
            "nine": {
                "name": [
                     "Ps3564",
                    "35355Ps"
                 
       
           
                ]
            },
            "tenCreated": [
                
                {
                    "tenCreated": "2022-02-10"
                },
                {
                    "tenCreated": "2022-02-10"
                },
                {
                    "tenCreated": "2022-02-10"
                }
            ],
            "elevenUpdated": [
                {
                    "elevenUpdated": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "elevenUpdated": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "elevenUpdated": "2022-03-24"
                },
            ],
            "twelve": {
                "thirteen": [
                    "fourteen",
                    "Do",
                    "Do again",
                    "Do work",
                    "Doone"

                ]
            },
            "fifteen": {
                "name": [
                   "Good",
                    "Not good",
                    "good"
              
                ]
            },
            "sixteen": {
                "sixteenCreator": [
                  "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan kowalski",
                     "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan kowalski"
        
                ],
                "seventeen": null
            },
            "eieighteen": [
               "Test test",
                "test test 10",
                "api test",
         
             
                
            ],
            "ninteen": {
                "ninteeneReporter": [
                  "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski"
                  
                    
                ],
                "twentyEmail": [
                "jankowalski@",
                    "jankowalski@"
              
                ]
            },
            "twentyOne": {
                "TwentyTwo": [
                "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski"
                   
                
                ],
                "TwnetyThree": [
                   "jankowalski@",
                    "jankowalski@"
                 
                ]
            },
            "TwentyFour": {
                "TwentyFive": [
                    "P186",
                    "P186",
                    "P186",
                 
                ],
                "TwentySix": {
                    "TwentySeven": [
                        "Plan",
                        "Plan",
                        "Plan"
                     
             
                    ],
                    "TwentyEight": [
                         "END",
                        "END"
                 
                    ],
                    "Thiry": [
                        "To Do",
                        "To Do",
                        "To Do",
                        "To Do",
                  
                    ],
                    "ThirtyOne": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I can convert this structure as CSV using transform message ?

I would like that my csv looks like this (it's only example):

```
two;three;four;five
199052;191;2022-03-24
109926;191;2022-03-24
       190;2022-03-24
       189;2022-03-24
       188;2022-03-24
       187;2022-03-24
          2022-03-24
```

Comment: The expected output doesn't make sense. There are 4 columns headers (`two;three;four;five`) but at most 3 values, with the other rows having 2 or 1 value, without extra separators. If the dates are from key five, what should be in column four?
Also note that your input has invalid extra commas in several lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the output should be consistent so I combined some of my previous answers and created this reusable function to generalize the method of generating a CSV (or record based output) from arrays of different lengths.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv  separator=";", header=true

// Converts an object with each value is an array to an array with key pairs useful to be used for emitting a CSV output
fun ObjectToRecords(o)=do {
    var columns = namesOf(o)
    var maxColumnSize = max(columns map sizeOf(o[$]))
    var maxColumnName = columns dw::core::Arrays::firstWith (sizeOf(o[$]) == maxColumnSize)
    ---
    o[maxColumnName] 
        map ((item, index) -> ( 
            columns map ($): o[$][index]) 
                reduce ($$++$) 
        )
}

var payload2 = {
  two: payload.one.two,
  three: payload.one.three,
  four: payload.one.four.five.five,
  five: []
}
---
ObjectToRecords(payload2)
```

Output:

```js
two;three;four;five
199052;191;2022-03-24;
109926;190;2022-03-24;
;189;2022-03-18;
;188;2022-03-18;
;187;2022-03-18;
;;2022-03-14;
;;2022-03-14;
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working perfect. Could you tell me why you use first the fun do an then var?

Comment: `do` is used to define variables or nested functions in a block. I used it inside the function to define local variables that simplify the body of the function. I encapsulated the logic into a function so it is easily reusable.